# Laravel 5: SELECT REPLACE() does not work

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, replace, eloquent

I want to perform a replace within a database query using [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html). In phpMyAdmin, it's no problem using it in a raw query, but Laravel fires an error:

Query:

```
$p = Products::select('*, REPLACE(abstract, \'[[name]]\', name) AS abstract')
->Paginate(10);
```

Error:

```
QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '*,
REPLACE(abstract, '[[name]]', name)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `*,
REPLACE(abstract, '[[name]]', name)` as `abstract` from
`products` limit 3 offset 0)
```

Eve if I try it with an array like this one, the error occures.

```
Products::select([ 'name', 'REPLACE(abstract, \'[[name]]\', name) AS abstract' ])
->Paginate(10)
```

Why isn't it possible to user REPLACE() here?

Comment: Just spit-balling, as I've never used laravel, but have you tried `$p = Products::select('*', 'REPLACE(abstract, \'[[name]]\', name) AS abstract')
->Paginate(10);`? _Docs seem to suggest `select` takes a list of field expressions; in your fist attempt it looks like it is treating `*, ...` as one field; and your second is passing a single array(?) rather than separate arguments, for each._

Comment: Yeah you cannot use raw SQL in select like that. There is, however also an option to use DB::raw('select *, REPLACE(abstract, \'[[name]]\', name) AS abstract'); I am not sure if the paginate works on the result, maybe you can test and let me know? ;)

Comment: @Uueerdo: No, this fires: 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'REPLACE(abstract, '[[name]]', name)' in 'field list' (SQL: select *, `REPLACE(abstract, '[[name]]', name)`'

Comment: @RobBiermann Your solution does not throw an exception but even doesn't replace the needle like expectet. It just replaces nothing... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectRaw` should be used, otherwise laravel querybuilder escape whole string as a field.

```
$p = Products::selectRaw('products.*, REPLACE(abstract, \'[[name]]\', name) AS abstract')->Paginate(10);
```